# How to return index of ArrayList<Field>

Tags: java, arrays, search

I want to retrive index of specific element of my list :

```
    ArrayList<Field> list = new ArrayList<Field>();
    list.addAll(profile.getFieldsList());

    Object privacyName = "privacy";
    int i = list.indexOf(privacyName);
    boolean doesContain = list.contains(privacyName);
```

There is a field containing "privacy" in the list but i is always -1 and doesContain is always false. Why this search doesn't work ?

Comment: Your List contains element of type `Field`, which cannot have the value `"privacy"`. Do you have some property of `Field`, for which you are having that value?

Comment: I think it is cause of Object you are using and not Filed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
         if (o == null) {
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                 if (elementData[i]==null)
                     return i;
         } else {
             for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
   }
```

You need to override equals for logical equality or rely on default for reference equality.

In this case `privacyName.equals(elementData[i])` is always false.

Answer (score 3):

> Why this search doesn't work ?

Because `list` contains instances of the `Field` class and you are calling the `contains` method passing a `String` instance.

To make it work you need to pass an instance of the `Field` class.

Comment: So how I can do this for 'Field' type ?

Comment: The problem is he's passing an instance of `String` which can't possibly be a `Field`.

Answer (score 1):

[From the Java docs for `indexOf`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

So your list does not contain the object `privacyName`;

Answer (score 1):

In ArrayList Index of method will based on equals method. In field class overide equals and hasCode method of Object class. And you told that "There is a field containing "privacy" in the list" . IndexOf Array will based on equals method.  As @rocketboy's ans, u need to overide equals as well as hasCode method properly. 
[Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)