# Java ArrayLists not equal even though they are

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I have two `ArrayList` which has `HashMap` stored in it. For e.g

```
expectedList = [
{
    id = 1, key = X, rowid = 1, id = 1, timeofday = 12: 12: 00,
    stream = A
},
{
    id = 999999999, key = Y, rowid = 2, id = 1, timeofday = 16: 12: 00,
    stream = A
}]

tableList = [
{
    id = 1, key = X, rowid = 1, id = 1, timeofday = 12: 12: 00,
    stream = A
},
{
    id = 999999999, key = Y, rowid = 2, id = 1, timeofday = 16: 12: 00,
    stream = A
}]
```

`expectedFileList.equals(tableList)` //returns false any idea why? Data is exactly same in both lists even order is same still it returns false. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you indent please

Comment: Is equals defined for the stored objects? If not that could be your problem.

Comment: I am sorry all that was typo both list has stream and not bundlesteam.

Comment: How can each HashMap contain two entries with the key "id"? Every key in a HashMap should be unique, and `HashMap.put(K,V)` replaces an existing entry if you use an existing key.

Comment: Doesn't looks like Java, more like JSON.

Comment: @S.D. That's just the default toString() outputs for Lists and Maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. The last element in tableList says `bundlestream=...`, while expectedList just says `stream=...`. Something is clearly different. *Edit: It appears the OP edited out this change; so it must have been a typo, which leaves:*
2. Are you sure the objects stored in the list implement equals() properly (or, in this case, the keys and values in the HashMaps in the lists)? If those objects' equals() are not returning expected results, then neither will the ArrayList's equals().

*Temporary Edit:*

@OP: Can you run the following code:

```
public static <T,U> void dumpList (List<HashMap<T,U>> list) {
    System.out.println("List:");
    for (HashMap<T,U> map:list)
        for (Map.Entry<T,U> e:map.entrySet())
            System.out.println(e.getKey().getClass() + ", " + e.getValue().getClass());
}
```

On both of your lists, e.g.:

```
dumpList(tableList);
dumpList(expectedList);
```

And post the output that it prints in your question?

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. I am sorry all that was typo both list has stream and not bundlesteam. Inside object are Hashmap and inside hashmap most of the things are String.

Comment: Every key and value in the HashMaps must have equals() properly implemented. When you say "most" of the things are Strings, that implies some of them are not. Are you *sure* all of your key and value types have equals() properly implemented?

Comment: See my temporary edit above. Would you mind running that function on your lists and posting the results for each list up in your question? That will print out the class names of all the items in the lists.

Comment: Hi @Jason you were right it worked thanks a lot there was one data type which was not String

Answer (score 1):

Data is different

```
stream=A
vs
bundlestream=A
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tableList has bundlestream=A

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the last object of data is different in them.

`stream=A` and `bundlestream=A`

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` for `ArrayList` is inherited from `AbstractList`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

> Compares the specified object with this list for equality. Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists
>   have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two
>   lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if (e1==null ?
>   e2==null : e1.equals(e2)).) In other words, two lists are defined to
>   be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

So, perhaps you have not overridden `.equals()` for at least one of the objects in your `List`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to understand how equals works in `ArrayList`.
And also you stored `HashMap` with in Array. 
This is how equals method works in ArrayList

```
public boolean equals(Object paramObject)
    {
        if (paramObject == this)
            return true;
        if (!(paramObject instanceof List))
        {
            return false;
        }
        ListIterator localListIterator1 = listIterator();
        ListIterator localListIterator2 = ((List) paramObject).listIterator();
        while ((localListIterator1.hasNext()) && (localListIterator2.hasNext()))
        {
            Object localObject1 = localListIterator1.next();
            Object localObject2 = localListIterator2.next();
            if (localObject1 == null)
                if (localObject2 != null)
                    ;
                else if (!(localObject1.equals(localObject2)))
                    return false;
        }
        return ((!(localListIterator1.hasNext())) && (!(localListIterator2.hasNext())));
    }
```

Yes, ArrayList internally compare each and evertObject in List, the compare by means of again, `equals` method of element in ArrayList.
In your case the element is HashMap, so U also  need to know how `equals` method works in HashMap. http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html
So, the sort and quick solution is that just overide `equals` method of your own. And dont forget to implement `hasCode` method also. 
[How to return index of ArrayList<Field>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105073/how-to-return-index-of-arraylistfield/18106052#18106052)
Sorry for the long Answer.